# String was not recognised as valid datetime format

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I have a asp.net page with Date input. It accepts date in the format dd/MM/yyyy. The code works fine if I run it through Visual Studio 2010. But if I publish the code then I get "String was not recognised as valid date time format" error...

I have set the system datetime format as "dd/MM/yyyy"

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what you are referring to here... Publish?

Comment: I would guess that your web server has a different language/culture set than you local development system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I always recommend putting exact date formats in your code, so you don't have to deal with any system differences.

For example, if you are accepting a Date from a textbox, you could do:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd\\/MM\\/yyyy", null);
```

Same thing when you output a date:

```
txtDate.Text = theDate.ToString("dd\\/MM\\/yyyy");
// instead of
txtDate.Text = theDate.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line in your webconfig you don't need any code.

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```